# No qualifying bean of type for a bean in the Action I'm testing

Tags: spring, junit, struts2, struts2-junit-plugin

I work on a project on eclipse, using tomcat, maven, spring, hibernate and struts. We've got 2 apps:
core that contains all the beans (services) and web with the actions views etc.

I made the JUnit tests for the services and decided to try doing some tests for the Actions. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

Action

```
@Action(value = "/modif/register")
@ResultPath("...")
public class A{
    @Autowired
    private ExampleService exampleService;

    public String execute(){
        Example = exampleService.find(...);
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
public class ATest extends StrutsSpringTestCase {

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        try {
            super.setUp();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws Exception{
        request.setParameter(...);
        //filling up the request

        ActionProxy proxy = super.getActionProxy("/modif/register");
        A register =    (A) proxy.getAction();
        String result = proxy.execute();
    }

}
```

Config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"web","core"} )
public class Config {
  //configuration
}
```

Each time i try to launch this test, I've got this error on the line `ActionProxy proxy = super.getActionProxy("/modif/register");`

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'web.action.A': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public core.service.ExampleService web.action.A.exampleService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [core.service.ExampleService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I got this error not matter wich bean I call. They all work in the core app and in my Action, i can even call them directly in my test without any error but it fails each time I try to launch a test.

Does anyone knows what could possibly throw this exception?

Comment: Why `super.getActionProxy`? There is `StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase` for JUnit 4.

Comment: *No qualifying bean of type [core.service.ExampleService]* you don't have that bean in your test context.

Comment: @AleksandrM Thanks for your quick answer. I don't really know about the "super". It's been 2 days that i'm on that test and i tried a lot of things. I just forgot to delete it. The thing I don't understand is that if ExampleService is not in my test context, why can i do an autowired on it and call one of his functions in my test?

Comment: Where? Try to use `StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase`.

Comment: Thanks! I've replaced "public class ATest extends StrutsSpringTestCase" by "public class ATest extends StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase<A>" and it seems to work now. But I don't know how to upvote your comment

Comment: *But I don't know how to upvote your comment* - Fixed that with an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BeanCreationException` is thrown because there is no `ExampleService` bean in your test context. It can happen because the right context isn't loaded for your action's test.

Since you are using JUnit 4, instead of `StrutsSpringTestCase` you should extend the `StrutsSpringJUnit4TestCase` class which will play nicer with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` and context loading.